# what is _description in class and why we use it?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I want to ask that in below code what is the _description and why we use it.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the class too?

Comment: edit it into the question please

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/is-there-any-object-attribute-called-description-62098?

Comment: yes i did it...
but i did not find _description in that document

Comment: @Usman so **why didn't you mention that**? If you've done research, *share the results*, rather than send other people down the same dead ends you've already explored. Please update the question to include what you have done so far, and with what results.

Comment: In my research i did not find the documentation related to my field.

Comment: thats why i posted it here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_name = "hr.employee.category"` is the technical name for the model which will be unique.

`_description = "Employee Category"` is the general name for the model which will be used for functional purpose (for user search etc). Also this name will be returned if you call model as many2one: `'model_id': fields.many2one('ir.model')` (_rec_name or name_get or display name)

Technically speaking your `_description` attribute acts as `name` field for `ir.model` same as your `name` field for `hr.employee.category`.

If you don't specify one, your `_name` will be used for both.

All your attributes will be mapped with this query

```
cr.execute("INSERT INTO ir_model (id,model, name, info,state) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (model_id, self._name, self._description, self.__doc__, 'base'))
```

It will be stored in table `"ir_model"`.

You can find your model details in `Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Models`.
Don't forget to enable the technical mode from `Login name dropdown(from top right corner) -> About Odoo -> Enable technical mode`.